# Browser refuses to execute inline script

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I'm running vue3 app using vite.

I want to add this script `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>` to my index.html; in order to handle payments with Stripe.

But I face these error in console:

> VM262:5 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-GEy81O1cBXMUtzNmiNgydJFrTMOlLkoqKvaHpNDLcrA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I did some couple of researches and with the help of official [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy); find out that we need to  add meta tag that allows this action:

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="connect-src 'self' https://api.stripe.com ws://127.0.0.1:3000; frame-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com https://hooks.stripe.com; script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com 'unsafe-inline'"
    />
```

But nothing changes...

First of all, why CSP is enabled in my project (Because I didn't see same problem in Stripe videos in Youtube) and then how can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Stripe.js _can_ do inline execution. (Do you see how you confuse your readers by stuffing keywords into your title?) Please revise to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: You need to read about CSP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP. Your webserver is likely adding one. I would look at whatever webserver you are using's documentation on how to modify the CSP.

Comment: You will need to add a nonce to that script tag on server side